# Отладка сокетов в андроид через USB

Tags: android, сеть, сокеты

При отладке клиента в андроиде через usb на девайсе возникла проблема - не создается  объект сокета.

```
// socket =(Socket) new Socket("178.57.226.134",1511);
```

Через LogCat видно что не выполняется код создания сокета.В чем может быть проблема? Связано ли это с какими-то дополнительными условиями при отладке на девайсе. В адресе указывал `127.0.0.1, localhost` пробовал. В указанном коде типа статический ip (сделал через "no ip"). Не работает!

Вариант с эмулятором не подходит, так как запустить его нет возможности из-за того что работаю на нетбуке и его процессор не поддерживает виртуализацию.

Код:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "test";

    public String host;
    public int PORT = 1511;
    private Button button;
    private Button connect;
    private TextView textView;
    private EditText editText;
    private Socket socket;
    public InetAddress address;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate");

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate onClick"); 
                new SendMessage().execute(editText.getText().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate onClick SendMessage");
            }
        });
        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate befor connect onClick 58");
                new ConnectSocket().execute();
                Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate after connect onClick 60 ");
            }
        });
    }

    class ConnectSocket extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
                Log.d(TAG, "ConnectSocket doInBackground start 71");

                socket =(Socket) new Socket("178.57.226.134",1511);
                Log.d(TAG, socket.toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "ConnectSocket doInBackground socket created 73 ");

                if(socket.isConnected()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "connected");
                    return "connected";
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.d(TAG, "fail");
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            return null;
        }

        /**Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result.equals("connected")) {
                connect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
        */
    }

    class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           String st = (String)  new String("Text");
           String date = (String) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(new Date());
            while(true) {
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "utf-8")), true);
                    out.println(" { " + params[0] + " }");
                    InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "utf-8");
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                    st = reader.readLine();
                    Log.d(TAG, st);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error ", e);
                  }
                return st;
            }
        }         

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textView.setText(result);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        try {
            if(socket != null) {
                socket.close();
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

Не создается сокет. В этой точке программа останавливается. Потом выдает ошибку, но прога продолжает работать.

Comment: Покажите полностью код. Иначе будет невозможно понять суть проблемы.

Comment: 178.57.226.134 - это ip вашего компьютера?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` и `localhost` - это само устройство. Так вы точно не подключитесь.

`178.57.226.134` -  внешний ip вашей машины? За натом? Тоже не подключитесь.

Comment: да это статический ip (вроде как. Делал его через сервис noip)

Comment: А что туда прописывать? Какой ip. Я даже пробовал то что для эмулятора 10.0.2.2

Comment: @Nikola вам к своему нетбуку надо подключиться?

Comment: Да... Сервер работает на нем.на нетбуке

Comment: @Nikola ответ мой смотрите

Answer (score 1):

`127.0.0.1` и `localhost` - это само устройство. Так вы точно не подключитесь.

`178.57.226.134` - статический внешний ip вашей машины? За натом, как я понимаю. Не сможете подключиться.

Если вам нужно подключиться к вашему нетбуку на `5111` порту, то зайдите на нём в настройки сети, посмотрите ip в локальной сети. Его и вбивайте. Это при условии, что Android и нетбук в одной подсети находятся.

Comment: в локальной там 10.203.13.13 Это тот ип что по договору.  И источник инета разный же получается, телефон и комп. Если  комп через вафай телефона подключить такое прокатит, подсеть одна получится?

Comment: @Nikola локальный ip и вбивайте

Comment: локальный - 127.0.0.1    Не идет

Comment: @Nikola вы же сами сказали, что `10.203.13.13`

Comment: @Nikola как успехи?

Comment: успехов нет. Думаю что операционка не пропускает. Пробую настроить (

Comment: @Nikola фаервол или антивирус стоит? Она приходится в Windows вручную в доверенные порты вносить

Comment: а как их вносить в доверенные?

Comment: Антивируса нет. Брандмаур пробовал настроить так что то он не открывается у меня. Ошибку выдает.....Ну буду разбираться сейчас . О результатах отпишусь...

Comment: @Nikola уверены, что всё же `10.203.13.13`? Обычно локальный адрес что-то вроде `192.168.x.x`

Comment: 10.203.13.13 это ip  при заключении договора от провайдера.

Comment: @Nikola так это внешний ip, как я понимаю. А вам надо посмотреть ip в локальной сети в настройках соединения (справа снизу значёк в трее).

Comment: смотрел в  cmd  ipconfig /all   там этот адрес. НО я сделал через сайт noip   себе статический (буквенный), и вот он работает . Т.е я в браузере забиваю адрес и порт и сервер реагирует. Причем если забиваю в браузер просто localhost или 127.0.0.1 и порт   ... тоже реагирует. А вот с телефона в логах пишет что связь прервана удаленым хостом. Так что проблема наверное в фаерволе. Но я что то не понимаю как его настроить

Comment: `127.0.0.1` работает так как та же машина. с Android он не будет работать. А с телефона вы в интернет как выходите?

Comment: 3G на телефоне.А почему тогда с браузера на nocola.ddns.net:5555 проходит (это статический адрес а порт поменял с 1511 на 5555)